# dataDirectory is not a member of io.gatling.core.config.GatlingPropertiesBuilder on gatling version upgrade

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Getting this error when I upgraded my gatling version from 2.3.1 to 3.3.1

I can see that dataDirectory and bodiesDirectory has been removed from gatling version 3.3.1 so what can be the replacement for that

```
value dataDirectory is not a member of io.gatling.core.config.GatlingPropertiesBuilder
    props.dataDirectory(IDEPathHelper.dataDirectory.toString)
```

Also getting error

```
value bodiesDirectory is not a member of io.gatling.core.config.GatlingPropertiesBuilder
    props.bodiesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.bodiesDirectory.toString)
```

Here is my code

```
val props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder
    props.dataDirectory(IDEPathHelper.dataDirectory.toString)
    props.resultsDirectory(IDEPathHelper.resultsDirectory.toString)
    props.bodiesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.bodiesDirectory.toString)
    props.binariesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.mavenBinariesDirectory.toString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found (and it works with gatling 3.3.1 and jdk 11)

```
val props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder()
      .resourcesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.mavenResourcesDirectory.toString)
      .resultsDirectory(IDEPathHelper.resultsDirectory.toString)
      .binariesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.mavenBinariesDirectory.toString)

    Gatling.fromMap(props.build)
```